# Почему на десктопе нужен один клик, а на телефоне — два?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Всем привет

Есть такой сайт : evrooptika.ua/women
И скриншот, где проблема : http://joxi.ru/xAeYkJKfev6pAy\

Есть нажимать на пункты, на которые указаны стрелки в веб-инспекторе на 320 - то логика срабатывает сразу.
Если захожу с айфона, то нужно два клика(сначала якобы отрабатывает ховер по нажатию(ват?) , а потом по второму клику - логика).
Никогда с таким не сталкивался, буду благодарен помощи
Спасибо

Comment: обрабатывай мобильные события типа `ontap`, вернее [`touchstart`, `touchend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это нормальное поведение. Сначала вызывается браузерное событие на `hover` а потом только `click`

Comment: Я попробовал отключить hover - теперь даже hover не добавляется)\

Comment: Прошу прощения, вроде заработало... было несколько ховеров)